# How to name a callback as a parameter when it´s either one or the other function

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

When `signupUser` gets executed I am `calling showSuccessMessage if signup is successful` or `showErrorMessage if signup fails`. Now I do not know how to represent this `in the parameter of signupUser`. The way I am naming it now as `showMessage` it only executes showSuccessMessage even if my signup fails.

I am confused about general / concrete naming of parameters.

```
// GLOBAL ARRAY for storing any DATA from the SERVER
  var ajDataFromServer = [];

  // Main ajax function using callback for posting data to the server
  function postAjax( sUrl , frmData, callback ){
              var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
              ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var ajDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    callback( ajDataFromServer, showMessage );
                }
            }           
              ajax.open( "POST", sUrl , true );
              var jFrm = new FormData( frmData );
              ajax.send( jFrm )                 
            }
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  // DO the SIGNUP, POST data to the SERVER with AJAX

  btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

      postAjax( "api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser );
  });

  function signupUser( ajUserDataFromServer, showMessage ) {

              if ( ajUserDataFromServer.status == "ok" ) {

                  //console.log( "SIGNUP SUCCESFULL" );
                  pageLogin.style.display = "flex";
                  pageSignup.style.display = "none";
                  showSuccessMessage( "Account succesfully created - Signup please" );

              } else {

                  //console.log( "SIGNUP FAIL - TRY AGAIN" );
                  pageViewProducts.style.display = "none";
                  pageLogin.style.display = "none";
                  pageSignup.style.display = "flex";
                  showErrorMessage( "Signup Failed - Try again" );
              }
          }

  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  function showSuccessMessage ( sSuccessMessage ) {
    var alblMessages = document.getElementsByClassName( "lblMessage" );
      for ( var i = 0; i < alblMessages.length; i++ ) { 
        alblMessages[i].innerHTML = sSuccessMessage.fontcolor("#549839");
      }    
  }

  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/
  /************************************************************************/


  function showErrorMessage (sErrorMessage) {
    var alblMessages = document.getElementsByClassName( "lblMessage" );
      for ( var i = 0; i < alblMessages.length; i++ ) { 
        alblMessages[i].innerHTML = sErrorMessage;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output? You are not even calling `showMessage`.

Comment: Well, have a `successCallback` and a `failCallback`. Or use promises with `.then` and `.catch`.

Comment: `showMessage`stands for `either showSuccessMessage or showErrorMessage`, and that´s basically my question cause the way it is, is  wrong. Since I don´t want to pass both in the parameter of the main function how can I do that ?

Comment: @codeDragon You either have to pass both (as you don't know beforehand which one will be needed) or use node callback conventions that use different call signatures of a single callback function for the error and success cases.

Comment: that´s what I was trying to do the node callback convention, could you give me an example of that in this scenario ?

Comment: The error case would call `showMessage(error)`, the success case  `showMessage(null, result)`. And in the callback, you'd use `if (err) … else …`.